# Why is there $6$ points on this graph?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Suppose set $A = \{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\}$ and you are asked to find a set $B$ where $A+B$ has exactly $6$ points on a graph. A possible answer of set $B$ would be  $B = \{(0,0), (1,0)\}$. But isn't set $B$ is already in set $A$? Why would there still be $6$ points in such case?

By meaning 'on the graph', that means sets are being illustrated on a xy intercept. For example set B would be illustrated as below

[image]

Comment: $A+B$ is defined as $$\{a+b\mid a\in A,b\in B\}$$It is different than $A\cup B$.

Comment: @march the graph should be illustrating set A + set B

Comment: What do you mean by "on a graph"?